# Javascript CF_HDROP Implementation

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to implement a [CF_HDROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CF_HDROP) drag and drop from the browser into another program? I am hoping to use a JavaScript website as a way to organize, search, and server a catalog of content on a local sever for another program.

While I have found a way to drag and drop from the browser as a download to the desktop or another folder. I have not found a way to have it act as a CF_HDROP clipboard format. My hunch is that this is not possible do the the sand boxing of JavaScript in the browser but I am sure someone smarter than me can confirm that.

Comment: are you referring to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx Shell clipboard formats are used to identify the type of Shell data being transferred through the clipboard

Comment: Correct, I am referring to the Shell clipboard format. I should have included that link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx#CF_HDROP

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for same problem for last few days, [DnD functionality in HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dnd) has some functions that manipulate clipboard data with setData() function. While it works good when you want to get something into browser, setData is working differently in each browser when I tried, most likely because of security reasons.

I used [ClipSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168/ClipSpy) for checking the clipboard data and used this html/js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="drag1" draggable="true">
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.getElementById( 'drag1' ).addEventListener( 'dragstart', function drag( ev ) {

    // Create data transfer facade so we can set custom data types (like 'commet').
    //ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("FileNameW", "\\fileserver\SampleVideo\Test.avi" );
    ev.dataTransfer.setData( "SomeData", "true" );
    //ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", "<p>Example paragraph</p>");
    //ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/uri-list", "http://developer.mozilla.org");
    // Some text need to be set, otherwise drop event will not be fired.

},false);
</script>
```

When checking drag and drop from Chrome I saw all my data go into "chromium web custom mime data format" while in Firefox data was set as intended. IE11 is not setting any data at all (also setting untrusteddragdata).

ClipSpy out from Chrome:
[image: Chromium DragData]

ClipSpy out from Firefox:
[image: Firefox DragData]

Since Firefox seems to support CF_HDROP to be set in javascript, I tried to add path of a local file so when I drag it into desktop it would copy the file into desktop. I couldn't manage to make it work.

While thinking about how to do it on Chrome I find a sample script in [Chromium issues:](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/attachmentText?id=163387&aid=1633870000000&name=dragTest.htm&token=ABZ6GAeMVy5XRotFiDd_f6fT3eKUN0W6zA%3A1454408866928)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Download drag-out test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function handleDragStart(evt)
    {
        var url = document.getElementById("downloadUrl").value;
        if (url.length > 0) {
            var parts = url.split("/");
            evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/octet-stream:" + parts[parts.length - 1] + ":" + url);
        }
    }

    function init()
    {
        var download = document.getElementById("download");
        download.draggable = true;
        download.ondragstart = handleDragStart;
    }

</script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">

Enter the file URL: <input id="downloadUrl" type="text" style="width: 500px;" value="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" /><br />
<br />

<div id="download" style="width: 400px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #ccc; padding: 10px;">Drag this box out of the browser to download the file above</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I test it on chrome, its somehow converting downloadUrl to CF_HDROP and downloads the file in the link. However its only working in chromium, I tried to find its documentation or a way to use local files or custom data, but failed anyway.

Comment: Btw my second script is same as this sample:

http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/gmail_dragout/  

this feature most likely added to chromium to enable dragout attachments from gmail to desktop.